# Inspec Resource (for windows server) for GPOs

Tags: windows, powershell, chef-infra, inspec

I want to make an inspec (chef) for diffrent GPOs.
I`m wondering to know is there any resource for GPOs (windows server).
because I dont have enough knowledge of gpos and how they work trough a powershell.
So, I appreciate if you send me any suggestion regarding to right inspect rb files dor gpos. (e.g read gplink, gpo health and system access , etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `command` resource and the `gpresult` command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

You may use '[audit_policy](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/resources/audit_policy/)' and '[security_policy](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/resources/security_policy/)' inspec resources